# How to set a container's size double of an image using percentages only?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an infinite slideshow of a panorama picture using HTML and CSS. The problem is that I can't set the proper width for a container which should be the size of the linked picture times two. It worked when I used pixels instead of percentages but my goal is to get a dynamically changing loop. If I set the width to 200% the container will be twice as big as the screen not the picture therefore it won't be a loop illusion.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.photobanner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  /*this should be twice as much as the image*/
  font-size: 0;
}

.photobanner img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*image is resized to fit screen*/
}

.first {
  -webkit-animation: bannermove 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photobanner">
    <img class="first" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Trafalgar_Square_360_Panorama_Cropped_Sky%2C_London_-_Jun_2009.jpg">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Trafalgar_Square_360_Panorama_Cropped_Sky%2C_London_-_Jun_2009.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Percentages are always relative to the parent, and can't work the other way around. Will the images always be the same size as each other, or all different sizes?

Comment: They'll have the same size as each other. The reason I'm using two images is the loop effect.